# Где ошибка в коде?

Tags: delphi, консоль

> Вывести на экран матрицу А (размерность NxN, числа вводить случайным образом ) в I четверти - 1, во II четверти - 2, в III четверти - 3, в IV четверти - 4. N-четное, например:
>
> `111222 
> 111222 
> 111222 
> 333444 
> 333444 
> 333444`

Вот код:
    program Project2;

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var i,j,k,n:integer;
    a:array[1..100] of array [1..100] of integer;

begin
  write('please enter n: ');
  readln(n);
  writeln;
  k:=1;
  for j:=1 to n do
  begin
    for i:=1 to n do
    begin
      a[i,j]:=k;
      if (i mod 2)=0 then
        inc(k);
      if a[i,j]<10 then
        write(' ');
      write(a[i,j],' ');
    end;
    writeln;
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Не забывайте в вопросе код оформлять должным образом.

Comment: "числа вводить случайным образом", - как это, как это?

Comment: это лишнее не от этой задачи

Comment: Кстати почему бы вместо
    
    a: array[1..100] of array [1..100] of integer;
не написать просто

    a: array[1..100, 1..100] of integer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы увеличиваете `k` каждый раз, когда индекс `i` увеличивается на 2.

```
if (i mod 2) = 0 then
        inc(k);
```

А вот, что нужно вам:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var i, j, d, n:integer;
    a:array[0..100] of array [0..100] of integer;

begin
  write('please enter n: ');
  readln(n);
  d := n div 2;
  writeln;
  for j := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      a[i, j] := (i div d) + (j div d) * 2 + 1;
      if a[i, j] < 10 then
        write(' ');
      write(a[i, j], ' ');
    end;
    writeln;
  end;
  readln;
end.
```